# Why does this cause an endless loop in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop, local-storage

This may be a dumb question, but why is the below for loop going into an endless loop in Chrome but not in Firefox? (Obviously, the loop test is where it's failing - I just don't know why).

```
for(var i = 0; localStorage[this.config.localStoragePrefix + i] != 'undefined'; i++)
   this.config.appCount++;
```

It's doing checking how many localStorage elements exist. For example:

```
localStorage['myPrefix_0']
localStorage['myPrefix_1']
localStorage['myPrefix_2'] ...
```

Would return 3.

Any thoughts on why this loops forever in Chrome?

Comment: Any reason you can't just use `localStorage.length`?

Comment: What happens when you remove the quotes around 'undefined'?  `'undefined' != undefined`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is because you are comparing it to the string representation of undefined, rather than undefined itself:

```
localStorage['asdf']
>>undefined
localStorage['asdf'] == undefined
>>true
localStorage['asdf'] == 'undefined'
>>false
```

So you have two options, you can

1) `typeof localStorage['asdf']  != "undefined"`

or

2) `localStorage['asdf'] != undefined`

Answer (score 5):

`localStorage[this.config.localStoragePrefix + i] != 'undefined'` always returns true, as you're comparing to 'undefined' string. Change to to `undefined` primitive or test using `typeof`

Answer (score 2):

it's because 'undefined' is different then undefined :P

Answer (score 2):

```
for(var o in localStorage) if (localStorage[o]) this.config.appCount++;
```

Comment: Explain what is happening here?

Comment: Sort of. It depends on what kind of object localStorage is. It is possible my code will count functions and other stuff... You might need to qualify the test